# Access 2013 Form Requery Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that has a parameter query for it's record source - the parameter query asks for an ID number, then the form displays that particular record.

Within the form are a number of buttons that perform various functions (change status etc...) and then requery the form.

My problem is that every requery obviously re-runs the parameter query and asks for the ID number - how can I make the requery use the current ID number and not ask for it?

The button functions are quite simple -

Me.SRStatus = 3

Me.Requery

Regards,
Garry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me.Requery` will execute the query again, so it will ask for parameters always.

Consider using `Me.Refresh` instead of `Me.Requery`

It depends on what you need. You open your form filtered by ID, that's perfect. Then the user makes changes, and here comes the deal.

If those changes are just editing the record, then you don't need to use `Me.Requery`. **Refreshin will update the record and show the changes without calling the query again.**

But **refreshing won't update if the record is deleted or if you add new records**. To show new records/update deleted record/reorder records **you are forced to Requery.**

If that form is just for editing an existing record, then use `Me.Requery` so the existing data will be updated without executing the query again (and then asking for a parameter again).

> You can read more about this
>   [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-or-requery-data-76e8c8b5-b8b4-49eb-a7d5-a472e742366c)

**UPDATED ANSWER:** OP said that Refresh works, but in event `Form_Current` got code that enables/disables the buttons according to a field value. So the right answer would be:

```
Me.Refresh
Call Form_Current
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I did try Refresh - and it does work, but I also have an OnCurrent form property which enables/disables buttons based on the current status of the record - using Refresh does update the status on the form, but doesn't update the security controls I'm applying to the form using he OnCurrent from property. In this example, if the record status is Confirmed, the Confirm button should be disabled - using Refresh doesn't disable the button.

Comment: Then execute Form_current again after refreshing. Just type `Call Form_Current` and all the code in event `Form_Current` will be executed again, and your buttons will enable/disable.

Comment: That's awesome - works perfectly. Thanks very much for your help!